# Tensorflow.keras not training and stoping with error 'No algorithm worked!' in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory

I created a CNN model and it trained properly for the first and completed all epochs but when I closed the runtime and came back after a day and tried to retrain. It gives this error.

```
NotFoundError:  No algorithm worked!
 [[node sequential_2/conv2d_4/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-7-5d7257468056>:45) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3464]
```

Note: I am training this in google colab
Here's the error code.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam' , loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset,batch_size=16,epochs=40,verbrose = 1,
         validation_data=val_data,validation_steps = 16 
         ,shuffle=True, steps_per_epoch=80,
         use_multiprocessing=False,callbacks=[callbacks])
model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/eyes2.h5')
model.summary()
```

Link to notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Qf05-Axd1gjuZhBDv7LwNtO_znIg4iKf

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook (i.e., one that does not depend on private data in Drive) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I added the link to notebook

Comment: Try downgrading tensorflow to 1.x. Recently colab was updated tf from 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: Does tensorflow.keras work in it

Comment: @Bharath please post it as an answer, so people can see this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading tensorflow to `1.x`. Recently colab has updated tensorflow from `1.x` to `2.x` as its default which might be leading to this error. .

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error message with Tensorflow when running a known-working model. As suggested by Bharath, it did appear to be related to version incompatibility.

However, I did not downgrade to fix it as this seems counter-intuitive and a step backwards. Here's an alternative solution that worked for me:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pandas numpy matplotlib # probably not necessary
$ python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu # if you have the old style packages installed
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade tf-nightly
```

The Tensorflow [installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) and [GPU installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) were useful when solving this.